# Laravel DevExpress Grid Adaptor

Tags: php, laravel, devexpress

I want to use Devexpress Grid on my projecet instead of DataTable. I used to yajrabox before but i want to column resizing, grouping and more like devexpress grid features.

For this, I want to do operations that I can control with laravel on the backend side, such as filtering, establishing a relationship with the model. But I couldn't find an adaptor like yajrabox for this. DevExpress has developed something for PHP, but this is not useful for Laravel. The repository I'm talking about;

https://github.com/DevExpress/DevExtreme-PHP-Data

Can you help me how I can use DevExpress with server-side integration in my Laravel project? Thanks.